# Intel Scalable Processors

Tags: hardware, central-processing-unit, intel, scalability

this should be a pretty straight forward question but might come out as ambiguous (might also be the wrong place to ask). I've been researching the newest and bluest Dell Poweredge and HPE server blades and they all support "Intel Scalable CPU's" and after looking those up a bit I'm not really getting what's so "scalable" about those processors. Their Bronze, Silver, Gold and Platinum levels are essentially i3 i5 i7 and i9 all over again but within the Xeon Category. Is that what's meant by scalable? Or is it a hardware feature that allows this generation and the next generation to match the same socket while improving overall performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "scalable" part refers to the internal 2D mesh interconnection, which permit to efficiently connect a greater number of core than the previous ring topology.

See [here](https://www.anandtech.com/show/11544/intel-skylake-ep-vs-amd-epyc-7000-cpu-battle-of-the-decade/4) for more details.

Comment: https://images.anandtech.com/doci/11544/xcc28cores.png Awesome thanks so much for the info! Found that png on the same site explaining the mesh topology, very nifty!